# mySQL randomly update column data from existing data

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know if it is possible or a way to update columns and randomly change the text around or obfuscate it?

I want to batch update email addresses to something random @example.com for my users table.

I have a users table which contains

```
(id (unique), firstname, email_address (unique)
```

So thinking

```
id.firstname@example.com // (e.g 2012.jane@exmaple.com
```

I know this can easily be done with PHP, but does anyone know a mySQL function that can do this?

Comment: `Update users set email_address = Concat(id,'.',firstname)`

Comment: Thanks this worked just has to add @example.com (e.g update users set email = Concat(id,'.',firstname,'@exampe.com')

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
update users set email = Concat(id,'.',firstname,'@exampe.com')
```